# Publishing Azure web app puts a connection string inside a connection string

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App (https://www.triviaweb.net/) and a connection string in the web.config that looks like this.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;initial catalog={cata};persist security info=True;user id={usr};password={psw};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I publish the web app using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.2 to Azure the web.config is transformed to this.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;initial catalog={cata};persist security info=True;user id={usr};password={psw};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

It looks like the transformation kind of put a connection string inside the connection string. I can fix this manually on the server to make my app work but would much prefer that the publishing works correctly.

I’ve never seen anything like this.

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Look at the part "provider connection string='metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider Connection String contains valid keyword/value pairs for the data provider. An invalid Provider Connection String will cause a run-time error when it is evaluated by the data source.

Make sure to escape the value according to the general syntax of [ADO.NET connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings). Consider for example the following connection string: `Server=serverName; User ID = userID`. It must be escaped because it contains a semicolon. Since it does not contain double quotation marks, they may be used for escaping:

```
Provider Connection String ="Server=serverName; User ID = userID";
```

Try changing your connection string from :

```
<add 
  name="Entities" 
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;
  data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;
  initial catalog={cata};
  persist security info=True;
  user id={usr};
  password={psw};
  multipleactiveresultsets=True;
  application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

to:

```
<add
  name="Entities"
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;"
  provider= "System.Data.SqlClient"
  providerConnectionString="data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;
  initial catalog={cata};
  persist security info=True;
  user id={usr};
  password={psw};
  multipleactiveresultsets=True;
  application name=EntityFramework;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

For more information, you can visit [Connection Strings in the ADO.NET Entity Framework.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings)